# Trouble with a UNION statement / creating new column that uses data from another column while keeping that column intact

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some issues with some SQL assignments I've tried google, I've tried asking some friends with no luck, I'm working on SELECT, JOIN and UNION right now, the current problem is:

Use the `UNION` operator to generate a result set consisting of five columns from the Students table:

- Status - a calculated column that contains a value of UNDERGRAD or GRADUATED
- FirstName - The FirstName column
- LastName - The LastName column
- EnrollmentDate - The EnrollmentDate column
- GraduationDate - The GraduationDate column

If the student doesn’t have a value in the `GraduationDate` column, the `Status` column should contain a value of UNDERGRAD. Otherwise, it should contain a value of GRADUATED.

Any help would be highly appreciated

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: *having issues* doesn't tell us anything about what your problem is. Add a clear description of the problem, the code and the error, and what you are expecting.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, EnrollmentDate, IIF(GraduationDate IS NULL, ‘Undergrad’, ‘Graduated’) AS Status
FROM Students
```

Details on `IIF`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

If this doesn’t help then, like Stu, suggested in the comments: provide Some more information in what you’ve already tried and what exactly didn’t work

**Version with `UNION`**

Had some time left so here is a version with a  `UNION`

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, EnrollmentDate, ‘Graduated’ AS Status
FROM Students
WHERE GraduationDate IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, EnrollmentDate, ‘Undergrad’ AS Status
FROM Students
WHERE GraduationDate IS NULL
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but I have to add a UNION statement into the select I can see if this helps me figure it out but none the less its all still appreciated

Comment: Do you have to add the UNION statement because your teacher/homework asked you to?

Comment: yep unfortunately

Comment: Like I thought, then lets hope your teacher does not read this ;-). And please read this [letter to students](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)